# Проблема с ссылкой на поток RTSP

Tags: debian, rtmp, rtsp

Пытаюсь на сервере запустить ретрансляцию rtsp потока. Пишу команду виду

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/user=admin&password=123&channel=1&stream=0.sdp -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/bana/stream_1;
```

И команда не запускается, так как ему не нравится знак `&`
Пробовал брать строку в кавычки

```
"rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/user=admin&password=123&channel=1&stream=0.sdp"
```

не помогло. Пробовал ставить перед знаком `&` знак `^` и обратный слеш - не помогло. Какие еще есть решения?

Или может кто подскажет как можно по другому ссылку построить, потому что у меня есть другие ссылки вида

```
rtsp://admin:123@192.168.1.1:554/Streaming/Channels/101
```

которые хорошо работают. Пробовал привести к такому виду первую ссылку - не работает

Система - Debian 8

Comment: параметры в url [отделяются от остальной части](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_URL) символом `?`. кавычки в этом случае обязательны, и лучше одинарные.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду написать так `rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/?user=admin&password=123&channel=1&stream=0.sdp` ?

Comment: да, и всю эту строку не забудьте заключить в кавычки.

Comment: получил такое `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, 1 reference frame, none(left)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`

Comment: а в конце еще это `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

Comment: ну, это уже совершенно иной вопрос, относящийся к программе ffmpeg и к тому, с чем она там связывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/user=admin&password=123&channel=1&stream=0.sdp ...
> ```

параметры в url [отделяются от остальной части](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_URL) символом `?`. кавычки в этом случае обязательны, и лучше одинарные:

```
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/?user=admin&password=123&channel=1&stream=0.sdp' ...
```